# Swagger is part of base URL for WebAPI (Routing)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

So I have absolutely no idea what happened, but suddenly Swagger became a part of my endpoint URL, meaning it is no longer url.com/api/Values but url.com/Swagger/api/Values. I am unsure of how this happened and I have looked everywhere regarding modifications of base URL etc., but I am sure I just made a tiny mistake somewhere.

**Configure()**

```
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "LA NOSA - FE API");
            });

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

**ConfigureServices()**

```
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext.AppContext>(options =>
                          options.UseSqlServer(
                              Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            //Register dapper in scope    
            services.AddScoped<IDapper, DapperManager>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                   ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                   ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                   IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
               };
           });
            //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a route attribute for your controller?

Comment: And if you do have the route attribute, do you mean the actual endpoint or the endpoint annotation when looking at the swagger page?

Comment: @Farshad

Thank you for replying. My route for all controllers are: [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

And yes, I mean that I before had the endpoint localhost:4400/api/Values which is now localhost:4400/Swagger/api/Values

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to move the `UseSwagger` and `UseSwaggerUI` to after `UseMvc`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your launchSettings.json may be there is some problem with urls

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking your time to reply.

Here is my launchSettings: (I have provided swagger/swagger as /swagger will return 404).
`
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44393/swagger/index.html",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
`

Comment: Change   "launchUrl":"localhost:44393/swagger/index.html", to "localhost:44393/api/Values"

Comment: That is already the launch url, the launch browser is not though (that is only for debugging).